# retrieve xml file using nsxmlparser in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

i am getting problem while reading xml files through nsxmlparser in ios,

```
<PRODUCTS>
    <PRODUCTSLIST>
        <PRODUCTDETAILS>
                <headertext> test header </headertext>
                <description><b style="font-size: x-small;">product, advantages</b></description>
        </PRODUCTDETAILS>
    </PRODUCTSLIST>
</PRODUCTS>
```

while i read the file using nsxmlparser i am able to get value(test header) for **headertext** but the **description** attribute value contains html tags so i cant able to get the result  `(<b style="font-size: x-small;">product, advantages</b>)`i am getting result as empty
How can i get the result as(`(<b style="font-size: x-small;">product, advantages</b>)`)  for **description** attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from a developers perspective I would not recommend using NSXMLParser due to it's laborious way to parse XML Files. There is a great write up about [choosing the right XML Parser](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).

I use [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) quite often.
You can find a quit tutorial of using it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274031/kissxml-not-returning-strings).

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's ok for 'smaller' files. but a DOM parser will eat up a lot of memory *btw, kissXML tries to emulate NSXML for mac so you can also read that docs*

Comment: I used it for files larger than 4000 lines and it worked well. But I  only used it to parse the Data and stored it into CoreData.

Comment: Reading xml file , i have only maximum 50 records if i use KissXml means it have so many class files and memory...

Comment: 4000 lines is small.... thats why I said 'small' -- Im using KissXML in a web scraper and it is **great** but when you have to deal with XMLs that are in the 10 MB+ range..... it might not be a good fit -- oh and it is slow in comparison!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the "b" tag is considered part of the XML structure, try escaping the '<' and '>' characters of the 'b' tag:
`@"&lt;b style=\"font-size: x-small;&gt;product, advantages&lt;/b&gt;"`
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Comment: that description attribute comming from service so that column having dynamic values .... if bold we can try like this suppose font and other tag came means how can i manage that ..